# how to change c++ compiler using mpicc and cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, openmpi, icc

I'm looking a way to change the compiler used by mpicc (openmpi) from g++ to icpc using cmake

I know that is possible by using the environment variable OMPI_MPICXX, but when i try to set that variable on cmake doesn't work, yet it does when I set it manually with an 'export'

the line used on cmake is as follow

`set (ENV{OMPI_MPICXX} "icpc")`

Answer (score 2):

Seems like cmake invokes a subshell when setting the environment variables and does not reach where you want it to be.

http://cmake.3232098.n2.nabble.com/Setting-environment-variables-td5529637.html

I'd do this by invoking cmake using a shell script, which exports the environment variable before invoking cmake.

```
my_shell_script:
export OMPI_MPICXX "icpc"
cmake path/to/source
```

Comment: +1, Also you can check in CMakeLists.txt that environment variable is not empty

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the use of additional scripts above cmake